# Wireless Driver rtl8812au no longer works in 19.10

Tags: wireless, 19.10, d-link

I have a D-Link DWA-182C1 wireless dongle which did work in 19.04, the latest update to 19.10 doesn't work. Ubuntu recognizes it, finds the driver and installs it but nothing happens. I am not experienced with Ubuntu and need step by step instructions on how to fix this.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/eoan/+package/rtl8812au-dkms lists versions for 19.10 - Which was installed?

Comment: No idea, how do you find that out?

Comment: I install the above driver but still doesn't work. Maybe I need to activate it somehow?